# Rails - Show a popup when user plan is insufficient for action - Without changing all views

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I want to restrict features **according to the plan** the user is subscribed to and **show a popup** if plan is insufficient.

That looks like an easy task, but my **requirement** is that I declare the actions and permissions in a single **config file** (maybe ability.rb) and not in the views. So that in the views, I won't have to do conditionals for each link or button

**Example:** The user clicks a link, the action is unauthorized because of *"insufficient plan"*, then rails sends a header or a HTTP error code (maybe HTTP 406 *upgrade_required*). 
Then a javascript on the page captures that error and shows a popup telling the user to upgrade the plan.

Obs: It's different from a simple redirect. Because the redirect takes the user away from the original page.

[image: Example user plan authorization flow diagram]

Can something like that be achieved?

What I **don't want to do** is to use conditionals on the views for each link and button.

**Example:**

`<% if current_user.can?(:do_action) %>
  <%= link_to 'Do action', some_action_path %>
<% end %>`

Obs: I'm using cancancan for authorizations and rails 5

Obs2: The error for *"insufficient plan"* should be different from the *"Action Unauthorized"* error.

I've searched around and didn't find a way to do this with this condition.
Thanks a lot for any light!

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be on a popup?
'Cause if not, you can catch the denied permission from cancan on your application controller and redirect the user to another page with your desired content. Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to your_page_url, :alert => exception.message
  end

end
```

Don't know if there's a way to catch that on rails and execute a javascript. Anyway, hope this helps... good luck

EDIT:

For handling the access denied in different ways, you can check which was the context that raised the exception. So, in my previous example, you can debug for checking:

```
  Rails.logger.debug "Access denied on #{exception.action} #{exception.subject.inspect}"
```

And that should be enough to allow you to redirect for a insufficient plan or a general permission error

About showing a popup... The only thing Rails can do is produce HTTP responses. You could try making an AJAX (XHR) call and returning JSON which JavaScript in the client interprets and responds to. That way you have full control over the actions in the browser. But this doesn't sounds good to me.

Comment: Nice! That's what I'm doing now for my users when they can't perform an action. But the result from an "insufficient plan" error should be different from the unauthorized action. 
And there is the need of a popup, so the user without the correct plan isn't removed from the page. What do you think!?

Comment: About handling the "insufficient plan" in a different way from the general unauthorized error, I made an update on the answer about that. The exception object should be enough for you decide what to do. But for showing a popup, I really don't know to do that in that case...

Comment: Ow! That I didn't know. It's a very good gotcha. Thanks. Then the one missing part now is to have the js on the page be aware of that. I'm researching that part right now and trying to do a PoC. I'll let you know if I find something. ;)